# How to disable default emmet or sparkup behaviour

Tags: plugin-emmet-vim

How can I disable default behaviour in emmet or sparkup?

I want to disable this expansion:

```
form --> <form action=""></form>
```

I want to set it to (without `action=""`):

```
form --> <form></form>
```